# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, owl-carousel

I have installed the owl carousel(npm install react-owl-carousel2). While running the code it is displaying the below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    eval
    ././src/owl.carousel.js?:1667:4
    eval
    ././src/owl.carousel.js?:1701:3
    (anonymous function)
    C:/xampp/htdocs/new-react/node_modules/react-owl-carousel2/lib/OwlCarousel.js:63
      60 | /* 1 */
      61 | /***/ function(module, exports) {
      62 | 
     63 |   eval("'
```

What do I need to do for 'fn' of undefined error?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using the carousel?

Comment: add jquery to your index.html, or declare it in the config file

Answer (score 1):

```
let owl_carousel = require('owl.carousel');
window.fn = owl_carousel;
```

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2537
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2206

Comment: Thank u fr your reply.Where i need to type this code .In which file

Comment: The file in which you have imported the owl carousel

Answer (score 0):

include this is plugin array
path : `Project\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js`

```
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      }),
```